# Unable to create an integration test for Django's reset password flow

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-authentication, django-contrib

I'm trying to implement an integration test for the password reset flow, but I'm stuck at the "*password_reset_confirm*" view. I already tested the flow manually, and it works fine. Unfortunately, the Django unit test client seems unable to follow correctly the redirects required in this view.

#### urls config

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views


url(r"^accounts/password_change/$",
    auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(),
    name="password_change"),
url(r"^accounts/password_change/done/$",
    auth_views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(),
    name="password_change_done"),
url(r"^accounts/password_reset/$",
    auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(email_template_name="app/email/accounts/password_reset_email.html",
                                         success_url=reverse_lazy("app:password_reset_done"),
                                         subject_template_name="app/email/accounts/password_reset_subject.html"),
    name="password_reset"),
url(r"^accounts/password_reset/done/$",
    auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(),
    name="password_reset_done"),
url(r"^accounts/reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$",
    auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
        success_url=reverse_lazy("app:password_reset_complete"),
        form_class=CustomSetPasswordForm),
    name="password_reset_confirm"),
url(r"^accounts/reset/complete/$",
    auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(),
    name="password_reset_complete"),
```

#### Test code

```
import re
from django.urls import reverse, NoReverseMatch
from django.test import TestCase, Client
from django.core import mail
from django.test.utils import override_settings
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

VALID_USER_NAME = "username"
USER_OLD_PSW = "oldpassword"
USER_NEW_PSW = "newpassword"
PASSWORD_RESET_URL = reverse("app:password_reset")

def PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL(uidb64, token):
    try:
        return reverse("app:password_reset_confirm", args=(uidb64, token))
    except NoReverseMatch:
        return f"/accounts/reset/invaliduidb64/invalid-token/"


def utils_extract_reset_tokens(full_url):
    return re.findall(r"/([\w\-]+)",
                      re.search(r"^http\://.+$", full_url, flags=re.MULTILINE)[0])[3:5]


@override_settings(EMAIL_BACKEND="anymail.backends.test.EmailBackend")
class PasswordResetTestCase(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super().setUpClass()
        cls.myclient = Client()

    def test_password_reset_ok(self):
        # ask for password reset
        response = self.myclient.post(PASSWORD_RESET_URL,
                                      {"email": VALID_USER_NAME},
                                      follow=True)

        # extract reset token from email
        self.assertEqual(len(mail.outbox), 1)
        msg = mail.outbox[0]
        uidb64, token = utils_extract_reset_tokens(msg.body)

        # change the password
        response = self.myclient.post(PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL(uidb64, token),
                                      {"new_password1": USER_NEW_PSW,
                                       "new_password2": USER_NEW_PSW},
                                      follow=True)

        self.assertIsNone(authenticate(username=VALID_USER_NAME,password=USER_OLD_PSW))
```

Now, the assert fails: the user is authenticated with the old password. From the log I'm able to detect that the change password is not executed.

A few extra useful information:

- `post` returns a successful `HTTP 200`;
- the `response.redirect_chain` is `[('/accounts/reset/token_removed/set-password/', 302)]` and I think this is wrong, as it should have another loop (in the manual case I see another call to the dispatch method);
- I'm executing the test with the Django unit test tools.

Any idea on how to properly test this scenario? I need this to make sure emails and logging are properly executed (and never removed).

Many thanks!

## EDIT: solution

As well explained by the accepted solution, here the working code for the test case:

```
def test_password_reset_ok(self):
        # ask for password reset
        response = self.myclient.post(PASSWORD_RESET_URL,
                                      {"email": VALID_USER_NAME},
                                      follow=True)

        # extract reset token from email
        self.assertEqual(len(mail.outbox), 1)
        msg = mail.outbox[0]
        uidb64, token = utils_extract_reset_tokens(msg.body)

        # change the password
        self.myclient.get(PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL(uidb64, token), follow=True)
        response = self.myclient.post(PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL(uidb64, "set-password"),
                                      {"new_password1": USER_NEW_PSW,
                                       "new_password2": USER_NEW_PSW},
                                      follow=True)

        self.assertIsNone(authenticate(username=VALID_USER_NAME,password=USER_OLD_PSW))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is very interesting; so it looks like Django has implemented a security feature in the password reset page to prevent the token from being leaked in the [HTTP Referrer header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer). Read more about Referrer Header Leaks [here.](https://portswigger.net/kb/issues/00500400_cross-domain-referer-leakage)

### TL;DR

Django is basically taking the *sensitive* token from the URL and placing it in Session and performing a internal redirect (same domain) to prevent you from clicking away to a different site and leaking the token via the Referer header.

### Here's how:

- When you hit `/accounts/reset/uidb64/token/` (you should be doing a GET here, however you are doing a POST in your test case) the first time, Django pulls the token from the URL and sets it in session and redirects you to `/accounts/reset/uidb64/set-password/`.
- This now loads the `/accounts/reset/uidb64/set-password/` page, where you can set the passwords and perform a **POST**
- When you POST from this page, the same View handles your POST request since the `token` URL param can handle both the token and the string `set-password`.
- This time though, the view sees that you have accessed it with `set-password` and not a token, so it expects to pull your actual token from session, and then change the password.

Here's the flow as a chart:

> GET `/reset/uidb64/token/` -->  Set token in session -->  302 Redirect to `/reset/uidb64/set-token/` -->  POST Password -->  Get token from Session -->  Token Valid? -->  Reset password

**Here's the code!**

```
INTERNAL_RESET_URL_TOKEN = 'set-password'
INTERNAL_RESET_SESSION_TOKEN = '_password_reset_token'

@method_decorator(sensitive_post_parameters())
@method_decorator(never_cache)
def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
    assert 'uidb64' in kwargs and 'token' in kwargs

    self.validlink = False
    self.user = self.get_user(kwargs['uidb64'])

    if self.user is not None:
        token = kwargs['token']
        if token == INTERNAL_RESET_URL_TOKEN:
            session_token = self.request.session.get(INTERNAL_RESET_SESSION_TOKEN)
            if self.token_generator.check_token(self.user, session_token):
                # If the token is valid, display the password reset form.
                self.validlink = True
                return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            if self.token_generator.check_token(self.user, token):
                # Store the token in the session and redirect to the
                # password reset form at a URL without the token. That
                # avoids the possibility of leaking the token in the
                # HTTP Referer header.
                self.request.session[INTERNAL_RESET_SESSION_TOKEN] = token
                redirect_url = self.request.path.replace(token, INTERNAL_RESET_URL_TOKEN)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)

    # Display the "Password reset unsuccessful" page.
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())
```

*Notice the comment in the code where this magic happens:*

> Store the token in the session and redirect to the
>   password reset form at a URL without the token. That
>   avoids the possibility of leaking the token in the
>   HTTP Referer header.

I think this makes it clear how you can fix your unit test; do a GET on the `PASSWORD_RESET_URL` which will give you the redirect URL, you can then POST to this redirect_url and perform password resets!